# Copy a C++ object at a pointer to a new pointer

Tags: c++

I have a pointer like this.

```
MyClass *p;  //MyClass is a complex class
```

I need to create a new pointer that has a copy of data that is inside the object pointed by p. After copying, I need to change my new object without changing the object pointed by *p.

When I do `MyClass *q = p` it copies the pointer. What is the correct way to do this?

I want to do something like:

```
MyClass *q = &p;
```

and when I now change an attribute of the object pointed by q, I should not affect the object at *p.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Is `MyClass` *copyable*? Can you do `MyClass a, b; a = b;`?

Comment: How do I find that? It is created by someone else.

Comment: The instructions (documentation)? Or you can just try it and see.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can try it

Comment: Not really. I am very new to C++.

Comment: Are you sure you need "a new pointer", or would just an object do? Pointers sometimes get overused.

Comment: I need a pointer because there are some methods that I need to call on that and these methods accept pointers. If I use an object I have to change all the methods too.

Comment: If you have implemented `copy constructor` for your class then what you can do is: `MyClass *q = new MyClass(p);`

Comment: @MKR That will not do. The upvoted answer explains why.

Comment: @Ron good point. I have missed  `*` while typing `p`

Comment: @harsh "*I need a pointer because there are some methods that I need to call on that and these methods accept pointers. If I use an object I have to change all the methods too.*" - taking a pointer as a parameter does not require dynamic allocation (unless the function calls `delete` on the parameter). You could just use the `&` operator to get a pointer to an object, eg: `MyClass q(*p); doSomething(&q);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyClass` has a *copy constructor* then you can simply construct a new one from the old one like this:

```
MyClass* p = some_function();

MyClass* q = new MyClass(*p); // use copy constructor
```

Of course you should be using *smart pointers* for this kind of thing:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p = some_function();

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> q = std::make_unique<MyClass>(*p); // copy constructor
```

This won't work if `MyClass` is *polymorphic*, in which case a *virtual* `clone()` function would be required.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this. Can you please suggest a good C++ book to start with? There are many on the internet if I search, but please recommend one.

Comment: @harsh This is a recommended book for beginners: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321992784

Comment: Thanks a lot @Galik

Answer (score 2):

First, your second pointer needs to be pointing to some allocated memory which has the same type as your first object:

```
Myclass *d = something();  //pointing to some object in memory 

Myclass *q = new Myclass(); //allocating space in memory for the same type
```

then you can use the copy operator to copy the data like this:

```
(*q) = (*d)
```

Comment: Thank you I got another answer, so I did not check this.